# Unable to save sharepoint page after Checkuot()

Tags: web-part, publishing-page, check-out

I need to update the sp page content by using C# code.

I have used below code to check out and update and check in.

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = pageFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
for (int i = 0; i < manager.WebParts.Count; i++)
{
    if (manager.WebParts[i].Title == "PageTitle")
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        if (pageFile.Item.ParentList.ForceCheckout == true && pageFile.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
        {
            pageFile.CheckOut(SPFile.SPCheckOutType.Offline,DateTime.Today.ToString());
        }
        manager.WebParts[i].AuthorizationFilter = ";;;;User Group";
        manager.SaveChanges(manager.WebParts[i]);

        if (pageFile.Item.ParentList.ForceCheckout == true && pageFile.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
        {
            pageFile.CheckIn("Published");
        }
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

But it shows below error while executing `manager.SaveChanges(manager.WebParts[i]);`

> The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes.